# jQuery append using for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was not really sure how to title this, but I hope that the question itself will make the most sense.

```
var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
  $("div[id^= " + str.charAt(i) + "]").wrapAll("<div id='" + str.charAt(i) + "' 
       class='alpha-content'></div>");
  //$("'#" + str.charAt(i) + "'").append('<span class="letter-header">' + 
    //   str.charAt(i) + '</span>');
  $('#A').append('<span class="letter-header">' + str.charAt(i) + '</span>');
};
```

So I am trying to append the span element to my generated html in a for loop, but for some reason i keep getting errors. With out the added span class, my html looks something like this:

```
<div id="A" class="alpha-content">
  <div id="someName" class="inner-content">
    <a href="someName">someName</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

What i am trying to do is add a `<span class="header-letter">` inside the letter with the corresponding div id tag. For some reason I can grab the letter just fine when I have it hard coded like `$('#A').append` blah blah blah... But if I try doing it with the `$("'#" + str.charAt(i) + "'").append` i get an error saying this:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#A'
```

I can't figure out where I went wrong... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the single quotes in the selector.

```
$("#" + str.charAt(i)).append
```

This will be equivalent a selector that looks like this:

```
"#A"
```

instead of this:

```
"'#A'"
```

The outermost quotes are just part of the string literal syntax, that I'm using for display purposes. The actual content of the selector string will be `#A`, while you had `'#A'`. The `'` doesn't have any valid meaning in that placement in the actual content of a selector string.